# GridView is adding new rows, but is not displaying values

Tags: c#, asp.net, session, gridview, datatable

**Background**

So I just started working in `ASP.Net` a few days ago. On my webpage I am creating a contact table for a user to populate and then submit to a database. Now what I have the user doing is entering information into various text boxes and then clicking an "Add Contact" button which then adds the content to a `DataTable` which is stored in a `Session` object. The `DataSource` of my `GridView` is the `DataTable`.

**Current State**

*Updated Click Event Code*

Whenever I click the "Add Contact" button a new row is added to my `GridView`, but nothing shows up in the cells of the `GridView`.

Code:

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!Page.IsPostBack)
        {
            dt.Columns.Add("First", typeof(String));
            dt.Columns.Add("Last", typeof(String));
            dt.Columns.Add("Email", typeof(String));
            dt.Columns.Add("Phone", typeof(String));
            Session["TempTable"] = dt; 
            GridView1.DataSource = dt;
        }
        else
        {
            dt = (DataTable)Session["TempTable"];
            GridView1.DataSource = dt;
        }
    }

    protected void AddButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        dt = (DataTable)Session["TempTable"]; // Fetching datatable from session

        DataRow dr = dt.NewRow(); // Adding new row to datatable
        dr[0] = "Jenny";
        dr[1] = "LastName";
        dr[2] = "Jenny@hotmail.com";
        dr[3] = "867-5309";
        dt.Rows.Add(dr);

        Session["TempTable"] = dt;   // update datatable in session
        GridView1.DataSource = dt;   // updated datatable is now new datasource
        GridView1.DataBind();        // calling databind on gridview
    }
```

**Question**

Is there a property in `GridView` that I am not setting or is there something fundamentally wrong with my code? Any help toward a solution would be fantastic. Thanks in advance.

**Solution**

I made the suggested changes by Bart De Meyer to my `AddButton_Click` event and set the `AutoGenerateColumns` property of my `GridView` to `true`.

Comment: I just copied and pasted your code and it works for me. Do you have some other code you have that you have not posted?

Comment: No, might be a GridView setting.

Comment: And it was. AutoGenerateColumns was set to false.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your Click event will be executed after the page load event.

In your click event:

- Fetch the datatable from your session
- Add the new row to the datatable
- Update the table in your session
- Asign the updated datatable as gridview datasource
- Call DataBind on you gridview

After update of the question. I tried it out:

```
private DataTable dt;

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!Page.IsPostBack)
    {
        dt= new DataTable();

        dt.Columns.Add("First", typeof(String));
        dt.Columns.Add("Last", typeof(String));
        dt.Columns.Add("Email", typeof(String));
        dt.Columns.Add("Phone", typeof(String));
        Session["TempTable"] = dt;
        grid.DataSource = dt;
    }
    else
    {
        dt = (DataTable)Session["TempTable"];
        grid.DataSource = dt;
    }
}

protected void btnAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    dt = (DataTable)Session["TempTable"]; // Fetching datatable from session

    DataRow dr = dt.NewRow(); // Adding new row to datatable
    dr[0] = "Jenny";
    dr[1] = "LastName";
    dr[2] = "Jenny@hotmail.com";
    dr[3] = "867-5309";
    dt.Rows.Add(dr);

    Session["TempTable"] = dt;   // update datatable in session
    grid.DataSource = dt;   // updated datatable is now new datasource
    grid.DataBind();        // calling databind on gridview
}
```

Should be working:
[image]

Remarks:
The Gridview ID parameter = grid
The button click event = btnAdd_Click

Comment: I edited my click event and the edits are now reflected in my question.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. It worked! I just had to set the AutoGenerateColumns property of my GridView to true.

Comment: Why did you set this one as the accepted solution? Yes, the click event is executed after the page load event, but this does not answer the question.

Comment: Well my old click event logic was incorrect. The one you see now in my question is not the one that was originally posted. It was one edited based upon Bart's suggestion.